# Listing top 5 users measured by most common rows in foreign key table

Tags: mysql, join

Here's a picture of my database structure:

[image: Observation recording - database structure]

[image: Criteria]

When I input an **Observation**, I'm entering a row into `Observations` but also 0, 1 or more rows into `Criteria`.

I'm trying to write an SQL statement which allows me to select the **Strongest 5 teachers in a specific criteria**.

So for example I'd click on `Questioning` (which might have an `ID` of `5` in `Criteria_Labels`), I'd want to return a list of 5 teachers (`Teacher_ID` from `Observations`) who have the most rows of `Criteria_ID = 5` in `Criteria`.

The statement that I've attempted to write is as follows:

```
SELECT t.Name AS Teacher_Name
FROM observations o
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON o.Teacher_ID = t.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN criteria c ON o.ID = c.Observation_ID
WHERE c.Criteria_ID = 5
ORDER BY COUNT(c.Criteria_ID) DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

However, it only appears to return one member of staff. I'm not sure I've got this right at all, but hopefully I'm along the right lines.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any reason the labels are in separate tables from what they refer to?

Comment: If you are using aggregate functions, you need to use `GROUP BY` to apply them to less than the entire dataset.  So a `GROUP BY o.Teacher_ID` might be an idea.

Comment: @Orbling thanks I'll investigate `GROUP BY`. The labels are in a separate table because otherwise I'd have redundant data - every row in the `Criteria` table would have a `label` in, which doesn't make much sense to me. I *think* it'd be classed as normalisation but I missed that seminar at Uni.. :)

Comment: It would only be redundant if the same label was in lots of criteria rows.  The way you have it setup looks like it's just a field split off.  Third normal form and BNF would keep that in the table, unless it was duplicated between many criteria or each criteria had more than one label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Teacher_ID, t.Name AS Teacher_Name, count(*) as total
FROM observations o
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON o.Teacher_ID = t.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN criteria c ON o.ID = c.Observation_ID
WHERE c.Criteria_ID = 5
group by t.Teacher_ID, t.Name
order by total desc
limit 5
```